# Whether using mipmap technique for mapping texture can save energy?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, mipmaps

Using mipmap when mapping texture can increase rendering speed and reduce artifacts. Recently, I wrote a testbench to characterize the power comsumption of 3D graphics, I found that when I use mipmap technique, the application consumes more power! Is it reasonable?
And, does the performance have relationship with the size of image mapped to object?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds surprising that you would see increased power consumption with mipmapping. But there are possible explanations why it could happen in some scenarios.

- One aspect is that sampling a mipmapped texture needs to read more texels. For trilinear filtering, you need 8 texels, while you only need 4 texels for bilinear sampling on a non-mipmapped texture. So mipmapping needs twice as many texture reads.
- The texture sampling unit has to do more work for the trilinear interpolation. Not sure if a typical sampling unit will actually consume more power in this case, but it seems possible.
- In unfavorable cases, mipmapping could actually need more memory bandwidth. Say you sample a polygon that uses the whole texture, and the texture is just slightly minified, so that the LOD is for example 0.5. In this case, you would need to read all of level 0 and all of level 1. Which is 25% more compared to reading just level 0 for the non-mipmapping case.
- Obviously generating the mipmaps also uses power. But as long as you do that once, and then use the texture many times, it will not matter much.

Aside from quality consideration, the general idea is of course that mipmapping would be more efficient and therefore use less power. At higher LOD values (i.e. stronger minification), I would certainly expect that to come into play because the memory bandwidth requirements will be lower. Or in other words, the cache hit rates will be higher.

In summary, my theory is that mipmapping might use more power if you're primarily sampling at low LOD values, while it would be more power efficient at high LOD values.

Comment: What if you are not using trilinear (or anisotropic) filtering, though?

Comment: Then most of my possible explanations would not apply. But mipmapping without at least trilinear filtering doesn't seem very useful. Wouldn't you get bad artifacts?

Comment: You can get a slight popping effect as the card switches LOD level. But this is the way it used to be done before trilinear filtering became cheap enough.